# Is it possible to access params of a redirected url in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, parameters, fetch

When I hit this url, `https://www.firstwebsite.com?redirect_uri=https://www.secondwebsite.com&response_type=code` it redirects to a page with a different url, `https://www.secondwebsite.com?code=aLongString`

I am trying to access the `code` parameter of the url that loads up on redirect.

Here's what I've tried:

```
fetch('https://www.firstwebsite.com?redirect_uri=https://www.secondwebsite.com&response_type=code')
    .then(getParams => {
        const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
        const code = params.get('code')
        console.log(code)
    }
)
```

However this just returns `undefined`.

I have also tried this:

```
const url_string = 'https://www.firstwebsite.com?redirect_uri=https://www.secondwebsite.com&response_type=code'
const url = new URL(url_string)
const code = url.searchParams.get('code')
console.log(code)
```

But this returns the first url, not the one I want to redirect to.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: You mean `url.searchParams.get('redirect_uri')` ?

Comment: Thank you @SimoneRossaini I just tried that but it only returned the origin of the redirect, and not it's parameters

Comment: See answer, is work..

Comment: Ah I realised why it didn't work for me. The `code` parameter in my redirected url comes from an additional parameter `response_type=code` in my first url. I didn't mention that earlier to save space but I see now it is important. I have edited my question to show this now.

Comment: `window.location.search` refers to the location of the current page you are _on_; making your fetch _background_ request, does not change anything about that. You should look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/redirected

Answer (score 0):

As you can see with correct `searchParams` work:

```js
const url_string = 'https://www.firstwebsite.com?redirect_uri=https://www.secondwebsite.com'
const url = new URL(url_string)
const code = url.searchParams.get('redirect_uri')
console.log(code)
```

After your comment, it's a little tricky but work if you now the url is always same

```js
const url_string = 'https://www.firstwebsite.com?redirect_uri=https://www.secondwebsite.com&response_type=code'
const firstSearch = url_string.split('?redirect_uri=');
console.log(firstSearch[1])
```

---

```js
const url_string = 'https://www.firstwebsite.com?redirect_uri=https://www.secondwebsite.com?code=aLongString'
const firstSearch = url_string.split('?code=');
console.log(firstSearch[1])
```

Comment: Thank you, but this just returns the word 'code' I need it to return the actual code that shows in the redirected url

Comment: i changed into `?redirect_uri=`

Comment: So close! This returns `https://www.secondwebsite.com&response_type=code` I need to return what the code is...

Comment: I don't know if you're kidding me :) The answer I gave earlier returned "code" which will be the code you need. It wrote "code" because the string said "code", but if it said "hello" it would have returned "hello", i add another snippet

Comment: Haha sorry I am not trying to kid you. My first url contains the parameter `response_type=code` but the redirected url has `code=thisIsTheCodeINeed`.

Comment: Can you past a real url with fake domain please?  Because i don't see `code=` into your example :)

Comment: As you can see from my last snippet is print code, i don't understand where is the problem :)

Comment: First url:
`https://www.firstwebsite.com?redirect_uri=https://www.secondwebsite.com&response_type=code`

Redirected url:
`https://www.secondwebsite.com?code=aLongString`

I need to access `aLongString` in the redirected url.

Comment: So in second website you will redirect another time? or is `https://www.firstwebsite.com?redirect_uri=https://www.secondwebsite.com?code=aLongString`  ?

Comment: `response_type=code` is hardcoded into the first url, but it returns a dynamic actual code into the redirect, which is what I need

Comment: So is that the real link : `https://www.firstwebsite.com?redirect_uri=https://www.secondwebsite.com?code=aLongString` like my last example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233841/discussion-between-sgt-pepper85-and-simone-rossaini).